# Having a problem with Vmware resolution in ubuntu(4k)

Tags: vmware, display-resolution

I have a 4k display monitor and running ubuntu as a virtual machine . In the system settings I get a maximum resolution of 2560x1600 but I have a higher reolution of 3840x2160 . Not sure the problem is with vmware or ubuntu. Any solution to this problem.

Comment: Related: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1013217

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with Ubuntu 22 desktop running on VMware ESXi 7.0   I figured out I had to add additional Video Memory.   Default VM had Video Card memory of 8MB and I had to increase to 32MB to get the resultolution for UHD 3840x2160 to work.  Now I have full resolution with Ubuntu via RDP working.

Answer (score 1):

Vmware Workstation 15, Ubuntu 18.10 Desktop guest.

VM -> Settings -> Display -> Monitors

```
Specify Monitor Settings; Set resolution to 3840x2160
```

VM -> Settings -> Display -> Display Scaling

```
Uncheck Stretch Mode
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but there is an easy solution.
Click the power button in the upper right hand corner of Ubuntu 17.10 then click the buttons that looks like a crossed wrench a screwdriver. Next scroll down to the devices tab. Select Displays. Change the Scale to 200%.

I know I'm answering this 8 months late but I could use the points ;)

Comment: This has **NOTHING** to do with changing the screen resolution.